# React-testing-library fetches XML data and allows user to continue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, msw

trying to do testing for the Post API call wherein the response is xml data. And also trying to achieve the passing of  the test case

below is the code to resolve

[image]

```
describe('CardDesignTestPage', () => {
    test('fetches XML data and allows user to continue', async () => {
        userEvent.setup();
        const promise = Promise.resolve(<xml>...</xml>);
        axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => promise);
        await waitFor(() => promise)
        render(
            <CardDesignTestPage />
        )
        userEvent.change(screen.getByRole('textbox'), { target: { value: <xml>...</xml> } })
    })
})
```

Comment: How did you mock `axios.post()` method? Only the mocked function has the `.mockImplementationOnce()` method.